# Reverse scroll view in XML

Tags: xml, android-layout, scrollview

I'm making an android app and would like the scroll to start at the bottom and then scroll up with a user input. Currently the scroll starts at the bottom and only swiping up moves the scroll and show empty space at the bottom, in the wrong direction. This is my first project, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/redCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
            android:background="#FF5F5F"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#F44336"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/houseButton"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/house_icon" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/foodButton"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/food_icon" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
     
        </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be done on recycler view using layout manager, if we first set Layout manager to `setReverseLayout(true)` and attach it to the recycler view, scroll will start from bottom as well as the items in it.